# Do we need to add a meta-data tag in AndroidManifest.xml to use Admob?

Tags: android, admob

In [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) it is stated that to integrate Admob in our Android App, we must add a meta-data tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

However, in two example projects, which can be downloaded from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android), both the 2 files AndroidManifest.xml do not include this tag. And when I test my app without this tag, the ad also shows normally.  So do we really need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is to the instructions when integrating Admob-6.4.1.

If you are integrating using Google play Services (which you should be from now on) then you will need to add the meta-data tag to your Android Manifest as described in [Integrating Admob with Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play)

Answer (score 0):

As per New `Google Mobile Ads SDK` you have to require **meta-data**.

Because of in earlier version we are used advertise sdk library so not require.

now **admob used play-services lib.**